# Alternate for controller action view in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms

Is it possible to create an alternate for a controller action? I'm working with a 3rd party module that uses a controller to display some content. I can easily override the controller action's view in my theme but I'd like to conditionally override the view based on the URL by adding a URL alternate. I know how to do this with regular shapes but am not sure if it's possible with views for a controller. The controller does have the `Themed` attribute enabled. I've tried implementing an `IShapeTableProvider` but am not sure what shapeType to Describe.

Is this possible? And if so, what shape type should I be looking to add an alternate to?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simpler actually. From your controller, return a shape result. The shape itself holds the list of alternates on `Metadata.Alternates`. So before you return the shape result from the controller action, `Add` the alternate to `theShape.Metadata.Alternates`.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. I was hoping there was a way to do it without modifying the code in the module and it currently returns a view model, not a shape. It's funny that you answered because I'm actually trying to override the views for the Stripe controller in the Nwazet.Commerce module. So there's no way to add an alternate without modifying the controller to return a shape?

Comment: Makes me doubt that you really need alternates, as I don't quite see what they will vary on. Wouldn't it rather be a template override that you're trying to do? If that's the case, just copy the template from the module into the views folder of your theme.